# User can edit response after completing survey, but edit permission needs to stay?

Tags: survey

Once the user is submitted the form, He/she should not have an option to edit or delete items.

I need the edit permission to allow the user to come back to his progress point in the survey.

Anything helps thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No fail proof, but here goes.

Make the final choice of the survey be "I am done" with a checkbox default to no.

Make a custom workflow that starts only on item creation.  The workflow then waits until I am done is checked and then move/copies the record to a duplicate list as system account. In the destination list, the users have no contribute rights.